# Create an ASCII art unjumble!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a string of ASCII art like such (This isn't ASCII art but it will do for the example):

```
abc
d e
fgh
```

Jumble it as if it was being displayed on a screen with one character per line, like so:

```
a
b
c
d

e
f
g
h
```

Print the result, wait one second, ±0.5 seconds before clearing the terminal and the print the same thing, but with 2 characters displayed per line instead of 1. Basically, the width of the display turns from 1 to 2.

```
ab
c
d 
e
fg
h
```

Note the space after the `d`. Repeat waiting, then printing with an additional character per line until the inputted text is outputted.

If you hit the end of a line when trying to print characters, then you insert a newline and print the rest of them following this rule. For example the input:

```
abcdefg
ab
```

Would print the following when the display length is 4.

```
abcd
efg
ab
```

You can find the effect of the terminal resize here: https://repl.it/GoeU/1. Run the program, then drag the thing separating the terminal from the text editor back and forth.

**Clarification:**

Once a line appears exactly how it was inputted, you can leave that line alone for future larger character counts per line.

```
abc
ab
```

should print

```
ab
c
ab
```

when the sentence length = 2.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so least amount of bytes wins!

Rules:

- Must print to STDOUT as the only output.
- Must clear the terminal, or create the illusion of clearing the terminal by adding 150 or so empty lines.
- Can take input through the standard methods.
- Default loopholes apply.
- Trailing stuff with the text is NOT OKAY.

This idea came to me when I was resizing a terminal with ASCII art on it. It looked interesting, so I decided to make a challenge out of it.

---

**Test cases:**

Since it would be too much work to show each step for each test case individually, I will review each answer to make sure it is valid. Make sure the answer can handle the test cases.

```
 ______   ______     __     __   __     ______      __    __     ______    
/\  == \ /\  == \   /\ \   /\ "-.\ \   /\__  _\    /\ "-./  \   /\  ___\   
\ \  _-/ \ \  __<   \ \ \  \ \ \-.  \  \/_/\ \/    \ \ \-./\ \  \ \  __\   
 \ \_\    \ \_\ \_\  \ \_\  \ \_\\"\_\    \ \_\     \ \_\ \ \_\  \ \_____\ 
  \/_/     \/_/ /_/   \/_/   \/_/ \/_/     \/_/      \/_/  \/_/   \/_____/
```

[This pastebin](https://pastebin.com/we30K2RR).

```
                        __/\__
                        \    /
                  __/\__/    \__/\__
                  \                /
                  /_              _\
                    \            /
      __/\__      __/            \__      __/\__
      \    /      \                /      \    /
__/\__/    \__/\__/                \__/\__/    \__/\__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bash (with GNU coreutils), 69 bytes

```
n=`tee x|wc -L`;for i in `seq 1 $n`;do fold -w$i x;sleep 1;clear;done
```

Saves input in temporary file `x`, then counts the longest line (GNU coreutils' `wc` has `-L` flag for this) and iterates for each console width from 1 to the longest line length. `fold`, `sleep` and `clear` does the rest of the magic.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.6, 124 bytes

Loops over length of input string like officialaimm's solution

```
import re,time
def d(s):
 for i in range(len(s)):print(*'\n'*75,*re.split(f'(.{{1,{i+1}}})',s)[1::2],sep='\n');time.sleep(1)
```

143 bytes to only go to width of longest line a al Frxstrem's Bash answer

```
import re,time
def d(s):
 for i in range(max(map(len,s.split()))):print(*'\n'*75,*re.split(f'(.{{1,{i+1}}})', s)[1::2],sep='\n');time.sleep(.5)
```

Uses "re.split((.{1,i+1}))" to break the string into groups of characters.  Because '.' doesn't match '\n', the groups don't wrap around from one line to the next. If the regex uses a capturing group, then re.split() returns a list with the matched groups at the odd indexes.  These are retrieved with [1::2].

Uses python 3.6 f-string to make the re pattern depend on group width i.

The * in front of re.split() uses python 3.6 unpacking to turn the list into arguments to the print statement.  Similarly, *'\n'*75, turns into 75 '\n' arguments to the print statement.  With the print keyword argument sep='\n', the result is printing about 150 blank lines to clear the screen, followed by each group of characters on a separate line.

Comment: This ones way better and shorter than mine. Great job! (y)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5 (<strike>238</strike> <strike>233</strike> <strike>229</strike> <strike>225</strike> <strike>223</strike> 222 bytes)

#### - Works fine  in the windows terminal; not sure about other platforms, because of the system-specific os.system("cls") command.

#### - The string passed should be marked by \n for newlines eg: 'abc\nd efgh\n'

```
import os,time 
def b(s):
 p=len(s);z=print;r=range
 for i in r(1,p):
  os.system("cls");l=0
  for j in r(p):
   z(s[j],end="");l+=1
   if(s[j]=='\n'):l=0
   if(j+1<p and l==i and s[j+1]!='\n'):z();l=0
  z();time.sleep(.5)
```

- Saved 5 bytes: removed unwanted whitespaces
- Saved 4 bytes: shorthand for len(s)
- Saved 4 bytes: Thanks to [sparklepony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64159/sparklepony) (shorthand for print)
- saved 2 bytes: Thanks to [sparklepony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64159/sparklepony) (shorthand for range as r and r(0,i) as range(i))
- saved 1 byte: Thanks to [steve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42156/steve) (0.5 as just .5)

Comment: Cool! I think you could shave off some bytes by using the code `z=print` at the top, and then changing all other instances of `print()` to `z()`.

Comment: I think you cold do the same thing you did with `print` with `range`, and instead of `range(0,3)` use `range(3)`.

Comment: `sleep(0.5)` can be rewritten as merely `sleep(.5)`